# why shutdown on udp socket blocks?

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, networking, udp

I'm writing a UDP server application for windows desktop/server.

My code uses the WSA API suggested by windows the following way (This is my simplified `receivePacket` method):

```
struct Packet
{
  unsigned int size;
  char buffer[MAX_SIZE(1024)];
}

bool receivePacket(Packet packet)
{
  WSABUFFER wsa_buffer[2];
  wsa_buffer[0].buf = &packet.size;
  wsa_buffer[0].len = sizeof(packet.size);
  wsa_buffer[1].buf = packet.buffer;
  wsa_buffer[1].len = MAX_SIZE;

  bool retval = false;
  int flags = 0;
  int recv_bytes = 0;
  inet_addr client_addr;
  int client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);

  if(WSARecvFrom(_socket, wsa_buffer, sizeof(wsa_buffer)/sizeof(wsa_buffer[0]), &bytes_recv, &flags, (sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_len, NULL, NULL) == 0)
  {
    //Packet received successfully
  }
  else
  {
    //Report
  }
}
```

Now, when I'm trying to close my application gracefully, not network-wise, but rather application-wise (going through all the d'tors and stuff), i'm trying to unblock this call.

To do this, I call the `shutdown(_socket, SD_BOTH)` method. Unfortunately, the call to shutdown itself **BLOCKS**!

After reading every possible page in the MSDN, I didn't find any reference to why this happens, other ways of attacking the problem or any way out.

Another thing I checked was using the `SO_RCVTIMEO`. Surprisingly, this sockopt didn't work as expected as well.

Is there any problem with my code/approach?

Comment: Have you initialized WSA at the beginning of your program? How does SO_RCVTIMEO behave? Can you add the socket creation and option setting code?

Comment: This will be rather impossible. The code is written on an another computer not connected to the network. I did initialize the WSA, initialization is successful. This is the only socket created by my program. And I use setsockopt(_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) AFTER calling bind, which returns zero (success)

Comment: I found this about the SO_RCVTIMEO option in MSDN which probably explains why it did not behave as you expected: "The timeout, in milliseconds, for blocking receive calls. The default for this option is zero, which indicates that a receive operation will not time out. If a blocking receive call times out, the connection is in an indeterminate state and should be closed.
If the socket is created using the WSASocket function, then the dwFlags parameter must have the WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED attribute set for the timeout to function properly. Otherwise the timeout never takes effect."

Comment: Have you read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738547(v=vs.85).aspx by the way? The comments are also a little worrying.

Comment: Have you tried using only `SD_RECEIVE` instead of `SD_BOTH`? Why do you want to `shutdown` a UDP socket?

Comment: @Holt I'm not sure SD_RECEIVE really does anything for UDP

Comment: @o_weisman According to MSDN doc, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481(v=vs.85).aspx, `SD_RECEIVE` is the only param which could do something for UDP socket. Actually, still according to MSDN doc but other link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916134.aspx, `shutdown` is unnecessary on UDP socket. In fact `shutdown` is used to end connection for connected socket like TCP, to tell the other side (your server) that you won't send anything more and will not accept incoming packets. It has no use for non-connected socket like UDP.

Comment: @Holt Actually after rereading the shutdown function remarks on MSDN I think we are both mistaken and both SD_RECEIE and SD_SEND affect following calls, but in any case shutdown is indeed unnecessary and you should just close the socket.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have also tries just closing the socket. The call to closesocket() also BLOCKS! I just can't have a break...

Comment: I guess this is why it's always best to have sockets on their own threads so it's possible to just kill them when they misbehave. But something just doesn't sound right about the information you gave us, particularly when talking about UDP sockets. It sounds like there might be a problem with your network card or operating system.

Comment: By the way, have you closed the thread that used this socket before calling shutdown and closesocket on in from another thread?

Comment: no I haven't. I wanted to close this thread gracefully rather then killing it and hoping that would terminate the blocking recv call

Comment: Well, the way I understand it, you can't use a blocking function call on a socket from one thread while another thread is already blocking on that socket. So if you call shutdown/closesocket from a different thread than the one you are using to call the blocking recv, it would lead to undefined behavior, as it seems you are experiencing. I suggest you either use a non-blocking recv and synchronize the shutting down of the socket to a time when the socket isn't blocked, or brutally kill the thread when terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run shutdown on duplicated handle? Shutdown on the same handle will wait any active operation on this handle to complete.